# OpenCV - Fit a curve to a set of points

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

This follows my post here: [OpenCV - Remove "white" artifacts from image and fit a curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852717/opencv-remove-white-artifacts-from-image-and-fit-a-curve)

I removed the extraneous white points in the image by looking for points across the diagonal at any given location. My result now looks like this:

[image: remove diag]

Now, I would like to fit a curve to the remaining points in the image. I have been looking through previous posts in OpenCV where some have suggested `approxPolyDP`. Is there a simpler way of fitting a curve and displaying it in OpenCV?

The idea here using Hough curves was a little too elaborate for me since my image is essentially binary: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/BOOKS/BANDB/LIB/bandb4_3.pdf

The final image is a (0-255) grayscale image of `w256 x h1024`.

**EDIT**

I just connected the points in the image using line segments. However, I would like to connect the points by fitting a smooth curve to all of them. I have searched SO for such a method and could not find a way.

[image: connect]

Comment: See [approxPolyDP](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html) might be helpful.

Comment: "Smoothness" implies (a) having some hypothesis about the process that generates those points - do you have a physical model for it? and for the "noise"/"errors" associated with them (their deviation from the assumed model)?   (b) having some application in mind for the curve - producing a pretty picture to look at is an application, but perhaps you have some specific needs for interpolation/extrapolation from your samples and model?

You need to answer both (a) and (b) to make progress.

Comment: @Haris I tried using the findContours and approxPolyDP to my code. However, I could not get it work because of access violation errors.

Comment: @FrancescoCallari a. No  b. No. I just need to fit a curve to the points.

Answer (score 2):

I think that catmul-rom spline will be a good choice for your task.

You can find implementation here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30838/Overhauser-Catmull-Rom-Splines-for-Camera-Animatio

**Answer for AHF's comment** (put it here by Qix advice):

This code sketch allows you to edit spline with mouse it uses the files from [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30838/Overhauser-Catmull-Rom-Splines-for-Camera-Animatio) (attach to your project: overhauser.cpp overhauser.hpp and vec3.hpp):

Left mouse button adds/moves a point, right removes.

The code is not very difficult, so I've made 1-channel modification (for compactness).

I guess you'll catch the idea.

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <cstddef>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "overhauser.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat result;
Mat Img;

vector<cv::Point2f> pts;
Mat curvesImg;
int selectedPt=-1;
CRSpline* spline = 0;

unsigned char LUT_RED[256];

// a case-insensitive comparison function:
bool mycomp (Point2f p1, Point2f p2)
{
    return p1.x<p2.x;
}

float dist(Point2f p1,Point2f p2)
{
    return sqrt((p1.x-p2.x)*(p1.x-p2.x)+(p1.y-p2.y)*(p1.y-p2.y));
}

int findNEarestPt(Point2f pt, float maxDist)
{
    float minDist=FLT_MAX;
    int ind=-1;
    for(int i=0;i<pts.size();++i)
    {
        float d=dist(pt,pts[i]);
        if(minDist>d)
        {
            ind=i;
            minDist=d;
        }
    }
    if(minDist>maxDist)
    {
        ind=-1;
    }
    return ind;
}

float F(float t,float x)
{
  vec3 rv = spline->GetInterpolatedSplinePoint(t);
  return x-rv.x;
}

float solveForX(float x)
{
    float a=0,b=1.0,c,e=1e-5;
    c=(a+b)/2;
    while( (fabs(b-a)>e) && (F(c,x)!=0) )
    {
        if (F(a,x)*F(c,x)<0)
        {
            b=c;
        }
        else
        {
            a=c;
        }
        c=(a+b)/2;
    }
return c;
}


int ind=-1;

void mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    Point2f m;
    m.x=x;
    m.y=y;
    curvesImg=Scalar(0,0,0);

    switch (event)
    {
    case cv::EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
        ind=findNEarestPt(m,5);
        if (ind==-1)
        {

        }else
        {
            pts.erase(pts.begin()+ind);
            ind=-1;
        }
        break;
    case cv::EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        ind=findNEarestPt(m,5);
        if (ind==-1)
        {
            pts.push_back(m);
            selectedPt=pts.size()-1;
        }else
        {
            selectedPt=ind;
        }
        break;
    case cv::EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if(ind!=-1)
        {
            pts[selectedPt].x=m.x;
            pts[selectedPt].y=m.y;
        }
        break;
    case cv::EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        ind=-1;
        break;
    }

    std::sort(pts.begin(),pts.end(),mycomp);
    if(pts.size()>0)
    {
        pts[pts.size()-1].x=curvesImg.cols;
        pts[0].x=0;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<pts.size();++i)
    {
        circle(curvesImg,pts[i],5,Scalar(0,255,255),-1,CV_AA);
    }

    if (spline) {delete spline;}
    spline = new CRSpline();

    for (int i=0;i<pts.size();++i)
    {
        vec3 v(pts[i].x,pts[i].y,0);
        spline->AddSplinePoint(v);
    }

    vec3 rv_last(0,0,0);
    if(pts.size()>2)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<256;++i)
        {
            float t=solveForX(i);
            vec3 rv = spline->GetInterpolatedSplinePoint(t);
            unsigned char I=(unsigned char)(rv.y);
            LUT_RED[i]=255-I;
            if(i>1)
            {
                line(curvesImg,Point(rv.x,rv.y),Point(rv_last.x,rv_last.y),Scalar(0,0,255),1);
            }
            rv_last=rv;
        }
    }

    line(curvesImg,Point(0,m.y),Point(curvesImg.cols,m.y),Scalar(0,255,0),1);
    line(curvesImg,Point(m.x,0),Point(m.x,curvesImg.rows),Scalar(0,255,0),1);

    imshow("Result",curvesImg); 

    vector<Mat> ch;
    cv::split(Img,ch);

    LUT(ch[2],Mat(256,1,CV_8UC1,LUT_RED),ch[2]);

    cv::merge(ch,result);

    imshow("Transformed",result);   
}
// ---------------------------------
// 
// ---------------------------------
//==============================================================================

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

    for (int i=0;i<256;++i)
    {
        LUT_RED[i]=i;
    }

    namedWindow("Image",cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
    namedWindow("Result");
    namedWindow("Transformed");

    Img=imread("D:\\ImagesForTest\\lena.jpg",1);

    imshow("Image",Img);

    curvesImg=Mat::zeros(256,256,CV_8UC3);
    setMouseCallback("Result", mouseHandler, NULL);
    waitKey(0);

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: but when we complete the code then is there any function through which we can move the curve of BGR ?

Comment: I dont undestand your question, can you reformulate it please.

Comment: you give the same suggestion to me so from that i am talking about this scenerio http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641208/how-to-draw-curve-on-control-points-using-opencv

Comment: What the is the main difficult? Is it mouse controlled curves?

Comment: yes it is mouse controlled curve , i want that we can change the curve shape through mouse

Comment: oaah thanks andrey , if you give the answer on my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641208/how-to-draw-curve-on-control-points-using-opencv so that we can solve that query

Comment: It's not a curve fitting. It only draws a line going though all points. what if we want a smooth curve not going through all points, but only influenced by those points ?

Comment: Ough, to "only draw" you need to estimate model parameters (fit your model to data). Model here is Catmul-rom spline, If you have more data DOF than you model degree, you will need to accept generalization. Check here for basic theory: https://towardsdatascience.com/the-relationship-between-bias-variance-overfitting-generalisation-in-machine-learning-models-fb78614a3f1e