# How to implement the following goals in opencv？

Tags: opencv

Well, I am a beginning girl in opencv learning,I want to achieve the following functions...can anybody give me more details and suggestions, thanks

1、I try to detest the closed shape successfully

2、I use the Findcontours() function to extract the outline.

Next, I want to find the inflection point ,so I use the Harries algorithm ..

Now I want to extract those sub-curves split up by those points...but I have no idea about it...

Sorry , Here is the replenish. My input image are black-and-white image . 
[the black-and-white image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOemm.png) 
Then I detect the  outer contour (PS. I don't know why there are something inside)...
Then I  marked the inflection point
[The inflection of the curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD3J0.png)

Comment: you need to provide examples of what you allready tried,. otherwise no one will help you

Comment: Seconding the wish for providing examples. Also, are the images always going to be black and white?

Answer (score 0):

You have to fit your curve using a math model f(s)=M where M(x,y) and s curvilinear coordinates. then you can calculate derivative at each point and find interest point.
You can use as math model spline fourier descriptors...

Comment: sounds workable, but how can I extract the curve in the image and transform it into a  curve function....and as far as I know , the Fourier descriptors is used to change the spatial domain image into frequency domain...So yo make me confused...can you give me some examples or demos to explain this?

Comment: What have you already tried with contour? You can find many links about spline and fourier descriptors on web (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898881/opencv-fit-a-curve-to-a-set-of-points http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/fd/node1.html)